# Jquery Ajax read data from database

Tags: jquery

OK I have this function to get data from the database

```
 function ajaxd(){
      $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "getJackpot.asp?dx=<%=id%>",
       dataType: "text",
       data: "",
       success: function(data){
         Jackpot =data[0];

alert(data[0]);
       }
    });
```

BELOW IS THE ASP CODE for getJackpot.asp

```
    Dim rs, sql, varJackpot 

    set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    sql = "select JackpotAmt from tblJAckpots where id = " & request("dx")
    rs.open sql, objConn, 3,2
        if not rs.EOF then
            varJackpot = cStr(rs("JackpotAmt"))
        else
            varJackpot = "Not Active"
        End If
    response.write varJackpot
```

When the above jquery script executes on the main page, the returned data[0] only contains the first digit of the returned value. The actual value is 6420.23 but the alert function only displays 6 and ignores the rest. What am I missing? I am suspecting dataType but not sure.

**Note:** Executing the getJackpot.asp in browser returns the correct value above with no errors.

Comment: what does `cStr(rs("JackpotAmt"))` returns

Comment: At the moment it returns 6424.35, but data[0] only has 6

Comment: I tried changing datatype to "html" but still no change. It still returns 6 instead of 6424.35

Comment: can you inspect the ajax request using developer toolbar/firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

> Jackpot =data;

I think data[0] will give you first character of your String input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an ASP guy but a few things which I found odd in your code:

1. First, don't send a `GET` request by sending a URL parameter. Instead pass the `dx` parameter as a value of the `data` parameter, which will be available as  a `POST` variable in the code that handles your AJAX request. (Depends on what works for you!)
2. Second, I guess you'll have to kill the execution after you output the value, the way `exit` is used in PHP after printing output for AJAX.
3. Check the data type of the `Jackpot` variable, I think you'll have to encode it as JSON. On the JS side you can then get the original value using `$.parseJSON`.

Try these steps, maybe it'll solve your issue!